# If $f(g(x))$ is one to one is $f(x)$ one to one?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

From my understanding $g(x)$ would not be one to one because the different inputs for $g(x)$ could produce the same result like $x^2$.  But what does it mean for $f(x)$?

Comment: Suppose $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with $g(x) = e^x$ and $f(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ must be one-to-one since if $g(x) = g(y)$ for some $x \neq y$, then $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$.  However, it could be that $f$ is not one-to-one, but $f(g(x))$ is. For example, let $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $g(x) = \arctan(x)$.